# Is it possible to control Windows Media Player From Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, vlc, windows-media-player

Is it possible to control (Play , Pause , Change Track) Windows Media Player using a Chrome extension ?

where can I find documentation about it ? I've found Microsoft SDK for C# for controlling WMP , but I'm looking for a way to control it from browser , liek old FoxyTunes for Firefox , but there I've found no alternative for chrome and there is a Foxamp that only control winamp.

Comment: In general, yes. But this is really too broad. Different players will have different APIs or ways to remote control them. Different browser extensions may have to use different APIs or "ways" to utilize such an API. Please try to limit the scope of your question.

Comment: best case for me is to control WMP from google chrome

Comment: Then revise your question (incl. title) like that. And probably try to narrow your question even more than that if you can. Even then, if you want people to help you, you should properly show you did some research yourself and/or tried some things.

Comment: I was curious whats the application of this? Doesnt VLC vids open in its own player, which has its own controls? So why take time to code controls into a browser when the VLC app is just one click next to it on the taskbar?

Comment: @Noitidart Because you'd need to switch back and forth between different windows?! Also, there could be advanced uses, like googling for the lyrics of the currently playing track with one click or whatever. There used to be the FoxyTunes Firefox extension that let you control a variety of media players, and display additional information, etc., but it is gone now after Yahoo first bought it and then later abandoned it.

Comment: @nmaier I edited question as you suggested

Comment: thanks for reminding me FoxyTunes , I couldn't remember the name of it , do you know any alternative that works with windows media player or at least vlc ?

Comment: You can find the xpi file of FoxyTunes on the net and then open it up and see how it used to do it: [Bing :: searchterms: foxytunes xpi](https://www.bing.com/search?q=foxytunes+xpi&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=foxytunes+xpi&sc=8-10&sp=-1&sk=&ghc=1&cvid=3bf2b3bb00354f94896ceac9203b20d7)

Comment: I've downloaded FoxyTunes and a Firefox 4 , it working well , inside it use a dll and the XPCCOM , So I need to write a C++ that communicate with wmp.dll and use it with XPCOM in extension for firefox , am I in correct way ? I'm still reading about alternative of XPCOM in google chrome.